# How do I change the format of Apache HTTP Indices?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, html

For instance, this index:

http://howto.unixdev.net/

Differs from this index:

http://gcc.petsads.us/

How do I change the format of the indices for my web server?

Answer (score 3):

The two URLs you posted, are for totally different protocols. The first one is a **FTP**, while the second one **HTTP** URL. The display format of the first is entirely up to the client software you are using, the second one is just a HTML file, dynamically generated by an Apache httpd webserver.

Apache httpd uses `mod_autoindex` for index generation (read its [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html)), which can be configured to produce custom output. Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +FoldersFirst +XHTML
  IndexStyleSheet "/include/style.css"
  HeaderName "/include/HEADER.html"
  ReadmeName "/include/FOOTER.html"
</Directory>
```

This allows you to provide arbitrary HTML files to be included before and after every listing and rendered using **CSS** stylesheet provided by you.

Comment: I was looking at several indices and I accidentally copied the wrong link. I've updated my question, please update your answer.